# sIFR 3 Changing <strong> Elements

Tags: sifr

I've recently implented sIFR3, but noticed that it is also changing unrelated  copy.

I don't want this to happen and don't have any  tags specified in my sifr-config.js file. I can't figure out why this is happening.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy any stylesheets which contain styles for the other content? It may be that those styles are hiding the text.

Comment: No I haven't copied over anything which would contain styles for the other content. It only happens if I add the inline tag of <strong> to copy after my sIFR declaration.